# network connection

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, network-manager

I have a rather fascinating problem and hoping some one could shed the light on it.

I have Ubuntu 12.4 LTS Server with 2 NIC's : 1. 10/100 2. 10/100/1000. eth0 & eth1 respectfully.

I used the eth1 (10/100/1000) NIC and manually gave an IP Address (192.168.2.50) and the server was working fine. Afterwords I updated the server to Ubuntu Desktop via the command line; the network worked fine. Few months ago I took down the server for maintenance in the house and couple of days back I re-connected the server back, but now it does not connect to the LAN with the static IP address I've given. But when I changed the eth1 NIC to DHCP it worked. But given it is a server I can not have it in Dynamic.

Here is what have tried so far:

- I have flushed the IP address a few times.
- I have reset the IP Address again a few times, but every time I give a static address and it does not connect to the LAN, nor the Internet.

Comment: What does your `/etc/network/interfaces` look like?

Comment: @ Jos... Here it is:  auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The Primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.2.100
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 broadcast 192.168.2.255
 gateway 192.168.2.1
 dns-nameserver 192.168.2.3 8.8.8.8


#Secondary network interface
 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.2.150
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.2.0
  broadcast 192.168.2.255
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  dns-nameserver 192.168.2.1 8.8.8.8

Comment: Though probably not the cause of your problems, I believe the `network` lines are redundant, as the network address is determined by the server address and the netmask. Try commenting them out.

Comment: @Jos, Thanks it does make sense... let me try that right now and will keep you update

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DHCP if it's working? You can always configure your router to use a static address for your server's MAC address, having the same effect and saving you from the hassle of having to configure your network manually.

Comment: Thanks. I should try that, cos every time I restart the server & go to Ubuntu Desktop the whole network goes for a six.... does not work at all... I have to remove the cable & connect a 2nd cable to get an IP... it sucks right now.... but the issue it was working before i took the server off line!! :(